# Как сжать List<byte>

Tags: c#, unity3d

Во что лучше сжать List, чтобы передать по RPC unity - как таковой list по RPC не передать

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словом «сжать»?

Comment: @VladD по возможно ускорить передачу - так как если конвертировать в string -> base64 то передача 3 файлов в байтах занимает ~5секунд.Файлы не более 4кб

Comment: Странно. Base64 занимает по идее больше места. Покажите, как у вас происходит передача в обоих случаях. А куда вы передаёте? 5 секунд — это как-то много.

Comment: @VladD servermanager.networkview.RPC("TEST", this.networkplayer, listdll); это если листом - но он не RPC не может отправлять листы - возможно ли конвертировать что-то попроще?ArrayList тоже не поддерживает

Comment: А в параметрах нельзя передавать просто `List<T>`? Почему не может отправлять?

Comment: @VladD rpc не принимает только простые объекты по типу string,int и тд - не указать List<T>

Comment: Вы можете разбить ваш лист и передавать например одну лишь строку. О чем я: есть у вас List<string>, добавляете к каждой строке запятую, и уже на другой стороне правильно обрабатываете.

Comment: `List<byte>.ToArray();` метод вернёт массив байт -- в чём сложность??  о_О

Comment: @Alias я же писал,что RPC не поддерживает передачу List,Arrayи Dictionary

Comment: @Сергей пардон, поторопился; вот преобразование в строку

`Encoding.Unicode.GetString(listBytes.ToArray<byte>());`

правда, не уверен в поведении для нечётного последнего символа массива байт.
Кст, если гуглить ответ на ваш вопрос -- первой строкой SO  =)

Answer (score 3):

Окей, у меня нет опыта с Unity3d, так что попытаюсь ответить насколько сам понимаю.

Если вам нужно передавать данные сложного типа, а интерфейс принимает только простой, то нужно данные сериализовать в строку перед передачей, и десериализовать после получения.

Например, популярным способом сериализации является сериализация в JSON через JSON.NET. Ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
List<int> list = ...;
string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
servermanager.networkview.RPC("TEST", this.networkplayer, content);
```

На принимающей стороне

```
string content = ...;
List<int> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(content);
```

Это может, однако, замедлить программу по сравнению с бинарной передачей, если она поддерживается. Попробуйте!

---

С другой стороны, [`NetworkView.RPC`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NetworkView.RPC.html) — устаревшее API. Возможно, имеет смысл перейти на новое API, а не бороться с проблемами старого.

Comment: смысл то имеет - но не имеет права - facepunch studios

Comment: Может поможет упаковка. Простой gzip на некоторых данных дает почти 10-кратное уменьшение объема.

Comment: @Monk: Упаковка-то хорошо, но сериализировать в строку все равно придётся